# Regular Expression..Splitting a string array twice

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, split

I have a text file with state-city values:-
These are the contents in my file:-

```
Madhya Pradesh-Bhopal
Goa-Bicholim
Andhra Pradesh-Guntur
```

I want to split the state and the city... Here is my code

```
   FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream("StateCityDetails.txt");
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    int h=0;
    String s;
    String[] str=null;
    byte[] b= new byte[1024];
    while((h=bis.read(b))!=-1){
     s= new String(b,0,h);
    str= s.split("-");
    }
    for(int i=0; i<str.length;i++){
        System.out.println(str[1]);  ------> the value at 1 is Bhopal Goa
    }
       }
```

Also I have a space between Madhya Pradesh.. 
So i want to Remove spaces between the states in the file and also split the state and city and obtain this result:-

```
     str[0]----> MadhyaPradesh
     str[1]----> Bhopal
     str[2]-----> Goa
     str[3]----->Bicholim
```

Please Help..Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What is the question? Does your code not work? If not, what do you not understand?

Comment: The code works fine sir but the result is not as expected...I do not know how to obtain the expected output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `BufferedReader` here, rather than the way you are doing it.  The code snippet below reads each line, split on hyphen (`-`), and removes all whitespace from each part.  Each component is entered into a list, in left to right (and top to bottom) order.  The list is converted to an array at the end in case you need this.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader br = null;

try {
    String currLine;

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("StateCityDetails.txt"));

    while ((currLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = currLine.split("-");
        for (int i=0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
            names.add(parts[i].replaceAll(" ", ""));
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
    if (br != null) br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// convert the List to an array of String (if you require it)
String[] nameArr = new String[names.size()];
nameArr = names.toArray(nameArr);

// print out result
for (String val : nameArr) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at com.psl.Client.main(Client.java:31)          names.add(parts[1].replaceAll(" ",""));  <----- its not doing this..gives an error here

Comment: @Bhavana_1622 Can you put any effort on your own to debug this?  My guess is that your input file has some lines which do not have a hyphen appearing.  I added logic to basically skip over such lines.

Comment: Thank you.. yes i will try... :) thnx

Comment: add this after splitting currline and adding it to a string:-                          while ((currLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
          String[] parts = currLine.split("-");
          for(int i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
          names.add(parts[i].replaceAll(" ", ""));}
       
      }          this works fine for me